# Javadoc not found for Tomcat runtime libraries in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, javadoc

Eclipse version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)
Tomcat Version: 9.0.46

I create a dynamic web project with the target runtime of apache-tomcat-9.0.46.   When I hover over something like "HttpServlet" it says "Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc."  Likewise if I press shift-f2 I get a "404 file not found".

If I go into "configure build path" and look at the apache-tomcat-9.0.46 library, specifically at the "servlet-api.jar" it shows the javadoc location as "https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs".    If I browse there manually I can find the javadoc for HttpServlet.

Here is what I noticed.  When I browse there manually the URL is:
https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

However, when I press shift-F2 in Eclipse and get the HTTP 404 it's trying to access this URL:
https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/java.servlet/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

Notice the extra "java.servlet" in the URL when trying to access it from Eclipse.  Anyone have any idea what the issue is or how to resolve it?  Obviously I used HttpServlet as an example, but it's affecting everything that's part of the tomcat runtime libraries which is super annoying.

Thanks!
Doc

Comment: Looks like the enhancement in https://bugs.eclipse.org/546945 possibly running a little amok, although I'm having some trouble reproducing it.

Comment: nitind - I'm not sure if it's relevant but I'm using the OpenJDK version of Java 11.  More specifically:

openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)


If there is anything else I can provide, just let me know.

Comment: What's the Compiler compliance level on the project's Java/Compiler property page? Otherwise it's worth a comment on the bug to see if they have any ideas on fixing it.

Comment: Thanks.  Compiler compliance level is 11.

Comment: I have the **same issue**. 

When I try to open the Javadoc from eclipse, say, for the `HttpServlet`. 

It opens up the 

https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/ServletRequest.html 

instead of 

https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletrequest

Comment: -- ^ (continue from above)

I downloaded the Tomcat lib from, https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi `64-bit Windows zip` 

Created a new `Dynamic Web Project`, set up the `New Runtime` as `Apache Tomcat v10.0` from the file above. 

All the .jar are loaded, and all attached with its own Javadoc location automatically. 

I can use the code with no problem. 

**But the Javadoc location doesnt work.**

Comment: -- ^ (continue from above)

I checked the lib for the project: 

**The attached Javadoc URL for `servlet-api.jar` is** https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs 

I have to change it to a local path and use an offline version of the Javadoc. 

And I have to do this for each jar file. 

(I dont know why eclipse dont support a good way to batch attach Javadoc for jar, there are like 30 jar I have, though this is another problem)